# Get all folders of a publication using Core Service

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Using Tridion Core Service how can we get existing folders of a particular publication. I am using SessionAwareCoreService2010Client class to create folders but could not locate in above class a proper method in core service to fetch list of all existing folders. Please answer with sample code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't test it at the moment, but it will be something like this:

```cs
var rootFolderUri = "tcm:1-1-2";
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Folder };
filter.Recursive = true;

var listXml = client.GetListXml(rootFolderUri, filter);

foreach (var itemElement in listXml.Descendants())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I would prefer to give you something to think about than some sample code that gets your job done (giving a man a fish and all that).

First - You say you're using `SessionAwareCoreService2010Client` hopefully because you're on Tridion 2011 GA instead of SP1. Otherwise I would certainly recommend using the [pre-compiled client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001905/precompiled-core-service-client-versus-generating-your-own-proxy) and the `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient`.

Now you say you want all folders. Do you want ALL folders in a publication in one call, or do you want to "walk" the hierarchy recursively?

All Organizational Items support a GetList call. With the CoreService this is achieved by using a `client.GetListXml(subjectId, subjectRelatedFilter)` call. If you only want folders, then you would start by creating a `OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData` object, and specifying that you want only objects of type `Folder` in the `filter.ItemTypes` array (along the lines of `filter.ItemTypes = new[]{ItemType.Folder};`

Now you can implement a method that would recursively call itself for every object returned by the client.GetList call and read whatever properties you need from the objects.

If you *really* need sample code, then I would recommend [googling for it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=tridion%20core%20service%20get%20list%20of%20objects)